# Deleting multiple rows in QTableView

Tags: qt, sqlite, qt4, qlist

While searching for clues on how i can delete multiple rows from QTableView i came across this function: [remove selected rows from QTableView](http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/4885-Remove-selected-rows-from-a-QTableView?p=25528#post25528)

Here is the code:-

```
   QItemSelection selection( ui.tableView->selectionModel()->selection() );
    QList<int> rows;
    foreach( const QModelIndex & index, selection.indexes() ) {
       rows.append( index.row() );
    }

    qSort( rows );

    int prev = -1;
    for( int i = rows.count() - 1; i >= 0; i -= 1 ) {
       int current = rows[i];
       if( current != prev ) {
          tableModel->removeRows( current, 1 );
          prev = current;
       }
    }
```

I need help writing the query doing that.I have been trying this:-

```
query.exec(QString("DELETE FROM %1 id IN %2").arg(tableName,rows));
```

but i think i should be using QStringList somewhere but i am still reading the QList examples.Anyone?.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you seem to be using a `QSqlTableModel`:

- in `QSqlTableModel::OnFieldChange` or `OnRowChange` modes, `removeRows` also deletes the records from the database.
- in `QSqlTableModel::OnManualSubmit` mode you have to call `QSqlTableModel::submitAll()` at the end of the loop.

If you were using a `QSqlQueryModel`, you would have to subclass that model to implement the deletion within `removeRows`.